# Order of positions of tensor/vector components in an inner/outer product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, metric-tensor, vectors, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

> Show that if $T_i$ are the components of covariant vector **T**, then $S_{ij}=T_iT_j-T_jT_i$ are the components of a skew-symmetric covariant tensor **S**.

The question is whenever working with equations of components form in tensor analysis, does the order in which the vector/tensor components are placed in an inner/outer product matter? i.e. $g_{\alpha \beta} \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial z^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial z^v}= \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial z^v}g_{\alpha \beta}\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial z^\mu}, ds^2=g_{ij}dx^idx^j=dx^jg_{ij}dx^i$ ?

I've always thought that since the components themselves are scalars, such an order should be irrelevant. However, if I was correct, then why don't the terms  $T_iT_j-T_jT_i $ cancel to zero?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're correct and the exercise is meant to involve two vectors $T_i,V_j$ and the combination $T_i V_j - T_j V_i$.

Comment: @ jacob1729 Ok thanks. But are there any exceptions to this "irrelevance of order" rule and how would we know that it is not applicable e.g. [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/473947/covariant-surface-vector) when clearly only the components of the vectors (scalars) are being referred to ?

Comment: In your link the differential line elements $dx^i$ are implicitly being multiplied by the anti-symmetric wedge product $a\wedge b = -b \wedge a$. I've seen that done in a few places before but really I find it confusing and would much rather they write the wedges explicitly.

Comment: Well.. actually $S_{ij}=0$ _is_ skew-symmetric and covariant